# An iPhone with dual sim capability?

Tags: iphone, sim

Is there any iPhone model with official dual sim capability?

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

And Apple does very rarely communicate on the future of there phones.

One of the reason for this could the place a sim takes in the phone. There were rumors that Apple would remove the sim system since It could be replace by something that take much less space.